# External paging for jqGrid-jQuery in Java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I have developed code as below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#records").jqGrid({
        height:350,
        datatype: 'local',
        colNames:['Policy Name','Policy Type', 'Time allowed (HH:mm)','Expiration Duration (days)','Session Pulse(minutes)','Description'],
        colModel :[
            {name:'pName', index:'pName', editable:true,sorttype:'text',width:150,editoptions:{size:10},formatter:'showlink',formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'javascript:' , showAction: "GetAndShowUserData(jQuery('#list2'),'",addParam: "');"}},
            {name:'pType', index:'pType', sorttype:'text',editable:true,width:150,editoptions:{size:10}},
            {name:'timeAllowed', index:'timeAllowed', sorttype:'text',editable:true,width:200, align:"right",editoptions:{size:10}},
            {name:'expDuration', index:'expDuration',  sorttype:'text',editable:true,width:200, align:"right",editoptions:{size:10}},
            {name:'sessionPulse', index:'sessionPulse',sorttype:'int',editable:true,width:200, align:"right",editoptions:{size:10}},
            {name:'description', index:'description', sortable:false,editable:true,width:200,editoptions:{size:10}}],
        pager:jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum:10,
        sortname: 'pName',
        autowidth:true,
        altRows:true,
        drag:true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        rowList:[2,5,10,20],
        viewrecords: true,
        loadonce:false,
        multiselect: true,
        /*
            onSelectRow: function(id){
                var gr = jQuery("#records").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
                if( gr != null ) jQuery("#records").jqGrid('editGridRow',gr,{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:false});
                else alert("Please Select Row");
            },
            editurl: "server.php",
        */
        caption:'Manage Policy'
    });
});
```

Now, I want to make an Ajax request to the servlet for next records when the user presses >> the (next) button of the [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start). I have searched much on the Internet, but I found a lot of PHP code, but I can not understand that PHP; I want to develop that thing in Java. How can I do that?

Comment: jQgrid auto manages this thing. You just need to pass full list of entries and it will show some entries on first page (as mentioned in its configuration) and rest on other page and so on...

Comment: But I want to manage external paging e.g. if user press next then it will call to server and it will get next records from ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As GPS said, the paging in jqGrid works by paging through its current dataset. You have to load a big set of data, and it will page through that dataset. There may be a way to get it to behave the way you want, but I don't know how.

For my grids, I use [the pagination plugin](http://tutorials.ajaxmasters.com/pagination-demo/) to trigger an Ajax call to get the next page of data. When the data comes back, I just clear the grid (clearGridData) and add the new set of data using addRowData.

I'm a [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) programmer, so I don't know how you'd do the database calls in with Java, but that's not really a jqGrid question.

To determine how many pages there are, you take the count of all the records that you'll be paging through and divide that by the number of records you will show on the grid per page.